# Retrieve Data from multiple OBJ to only one OBJ javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I need your help I would like to retrieve data from this array of Multiple objects to a single OBJ

Current format:

```js
    [
  {
    "name": "Field 1",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Field 2",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ]
  }
]
```

To this format ( For each multiple OBJ.caracvalue into one OBJ ):

```js
{
  "caracvalue": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you want to achieve is a reduce operation.
You can achieve it using the following code;

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    "name": "Field 1",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Field 2",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ]
  }
];

const resultObject = {
    caracValue: arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return [...acc, ...curr.caracvalue];
    }, []),
}

console.log(resultObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can collect it through the `forEach` function over the initial array.

```js
var array = [{
      "name": "Field 1",
      "carac": "Format carte mère",
      "caracvalue": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Field 2",
      "carac": "Format carte mère",
      "caracvalue": [
        "3",
        "4"
      ]
    }
  ],
  collection = {
    caracvalue: []
  };

array.forEach(function(obj) {
  collection.caracvalue = collection.caracvalue.concat(obj.caracvalue);
});

console.log(collection);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I would `let k = 'caracvalue'; collection[k] = collection[k].concat(obj[k]);`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var arr = [
  {
    "name": "Field 1",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Field 2",
    "carac": "Format carte mère",
    "caracvalue": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ]
  }
], result=[], key = "caracvalue";
        for(var i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++)
        {
            result = result.concat(arr[i][key]);
        }
        console.log(result);
```